# How to split trajectories into segment in R

Tags: r

I want to separate the trajectory into **6 segments** in the `trip id` column based on distance. Every segment will have the start point and endpoint.

This is what the sample looks like:

```
                     vehicle_id     time trip_id location_lat location_lon
 1: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:05:24       1     13.67530     100.6345
 2: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:06:14       1     13.67534     100.6359
 3: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:08:14       1     13.67805     100.6307
 4: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:09:14       1     13.67829     100.6239
 5: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:15:14       1     13.66856     100.6324
 6: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:18:14       1     13.66252     100.6599
 7: Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:20:14       1     13.65382     100.6756
 8: /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 22:37:30   44498     13.91795     100.6832
 9: /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 22:38:30   44498     13.91173     100.6766
10: /+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 22:40:30   44498     13.90366     100.6679
```

```
my.df <- data.table(structure(list(vehicle_id = c("Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q","Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q", "Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q","Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q", "Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q","Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q", "Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q","/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8", "/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8","/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8"), time = c("00:05:24", "00:06:14","00:08:14", "00:09:14", "00:15:14", "00:18:14", "00:20:14", "22:37:30","22:38:30", "22:40:30"), trip_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 44498L, 44498L, 44498L), location_lat = c(13.6753, 13.67534,13.67805, 13.67829, 13.66856, 13.66252, 13.65382, 13.91795, 13.91173,13.90366), location_lon = c(100.63453, 100.63586, 100.63067,100.62387, 100.63235, 100.65986, 100.67562, 100.68322, 100.67663,100.66788)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table","data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001634bed1ef0>))
```

So, my output should look หomething like this;

```
                vehicle_id     time  trip_id   1_seg              2_seg              3_seg                4_seg              5_seg              6_seg
Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5dHI78IK/Q 00:05:24       1   13.67530,100.6345  13.67534,100.6359  13.67805,100.6307    13.67829,100.6239  13.66252,100.6599  13.65382,100.6756
/+bx80f3gOoPMoFBsS+3xX6jpi8 22:37:30   44498   13.91795,100.6832  13.91173,100.6766  13.90366,100.6679    NA                 NA                 NA
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: why first vehicle's `4-seg` and `5_seg` values same with those of first vehicle?  What happens when there are `!=5` stops in between?

Comment: what is the distance criteria?

Comment: @AnilGoyal It's just my example results. If that's trip has a row less than 5 points, it should be `NA` in that values. And separation distances should be the average between each location in `trip id` (i.e., based on the length).

Comment: Yasumin, Now that you have edited you data, let me tell you that, still you have counted only two simple possibilities and not included enough logics to handle other very probable possibilities such as when there are >5 intermediate stops but actually <5 fulfill your criteria..

Comment: @AnilGoyal let me adjust my criteria then, can I set something from 5 into 6 segments. If there are >6 intermediate stops but actually <6 fulfil as you mentioned. Can we set that value into `NA` or `FALSE`? Is that enough logics? That means I want to focus only on the average distance the rest is not considered.

Comment: Yes you please give me advice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231650/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-yasumin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on discussion in chat above, I propose a solution/strategy based on quantiles instead.  Where there are more than `N` stops per trip, quartiles will be used after rounding off, otherwise NAs will be used.

*I used the data you shared on drive*

*The result for first 30 lines/obs is as under (there were 3 trips with 20, 7 and 3 stops respectively)*

```
library(tidyverse)

#Store your N
N <- 6

#code
df %>%
  unite("lat_lon", location_lat, location_lon, sep = ', ') %>%
  group_by(vehicle_id, trip_id) %>%
  summarise(d1 = n(),
            time = list(time),
            lat_lon = list(lat_lon), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(time = ifelse(d1 >= N, 
                       map(time, ~ .x[round(quantile(seq_len(length(.x)), probs = seq_len(N)/N))]), 
                       time
                       ),
         lat_lon = ifelse(d1 >= N, 
                          map(lat_lon, ~ .x[round(quantile(seq_len(length(.x)), probs = seq_len(N)/N))]), 
                          lat_lon
                          )
         ) %>%
  select(-d1) %>% 
  mutate(lat_lon = map(lat_lon, ~ .x %>% setNames(paste('seg', seq_len(length(.x)), sep = '_')))) %>%
  unnest_wider(lat_lon) 

# A tibble: 3 x 9
  vehicle_id           trip_id time     seg_1         seg_2        seg_3        seg_4        seg_5        seg_6       
  <chr>                  <int> <list>   <chr>         <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1 Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5d~       1 <chr [6~ 13.67829, 10~ 13.65382, 1~ 13.63679, 1~ 13.65828, 1~ 13.65828, 1~ 13.65828, 1~
2 Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5d~       2 <chr [6~ 13.66859, 10~ 13.66353, 1~ 13.66353, 1~ 13.66353, 1~ 13.65958, 1~ 13.65258, 1~
3 Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO5d~       3 <chr [3~ 13.63345, 10~ 13.63345, 1~ 13.63345, 1~ NA           NA           NA
```

Try it for other `N` say 7

```
N <- 7
#code
df %>%
  unite("lat_lon", location_lat, location_lon, sep = ', ') %>%
  group_by(vehicle_id, trip_id) %>%
  summarise(d1 = n(),
            time = list(time),
            lat_lon = list(lat_lon), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(time = ifelse(d1 >= N, 
                       map(time, ~ .x[round(quantile(seq_len(length(.x)), probs = seq_len(N)/N))]), 
                       time
                       ),
         lat_lon = ifelse(d1 >= N, 
                          map(lat_lon, ~ .x[round(quantile(seq_len(length(.x)), probs = seq_len(N)/N))]), 
                          lat_lon
                          )
         ) %>%
  select(-d1) %>% 
  mutate(lat_lon = map(lat_lon, ~ .x %>% setNames(paste('seg', seq_len(length(.x)), sep = '_')))) %>%
  unnest_wider(lat_lon)

# A tibble: 3 x 10
  vehicle_id         trip_id time    seg_1       seg_2       seg_3       seg_4       seg_5       seg_6      seg_7     
  <chr>                <int> <list>  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr>     
1 Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO~       1 <chr [~ 13.67829, ~ 13.66252, ~ 13.6436, 1~ 13.65828, ~ 13.65828, ~ 13.65828,~ 13.65828,~
2 Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO~       2 <chr [~ 13.66859, ~ 13.66353, ~ 13.66353, ~ 13.66353, ~ 13.66353, ~ 13.65958,~ 13.65258,~
3 Zz3yE90z++QmTX2QO~       3 <chr [~ 13.63345, ~ 13.63345, ~ 13.63345, ~ NA          NA          NA         NA
```

Comment: Yes,  it worked! Thank you very much. However, may I ask you more, what if I want to split into 6 segments, not 5? Can I do it?